# Replace existing function call with the new request in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a range slider that runs a function on `(input)` using the ngModel value like below:

```
<input type="range" min="6" max="60" step="6" [(ngModel)]="term" (input)="calculateTerm(this.term)" class="slider" id="term">
```

And a calculation in the component that adds five to the slider number (my actual calculation is more complicated but just for example)

```
calculateTerm(term: number) {
    this.calculatedTerm = term + 5;
}
```

If I go nuts and scroll up and down the slider a few times and then take my hand away from the mouse the queued requests keep going one by one until they've all been completed. What I want to be able to do is when the slider is moved it simply stops the request it's on and starts the new one so they don't all que up behind each other.

I've tried doing a few bits of research by looking at the (input) documentation and what not but I can't seem to find anything that stops this que forming. Is there a way to do this in Angular/Typescript?

Edit: I did previously use the `(change)` event, but I also need the calculation to be completed before the mouse button is lifted - which doesn't happen with `(change)`

Comment: I'm not sure where's the actual request to the server in your code, but check out `throttleTime` in RxJS, maybe also `exhaustMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use formcontrol together with rxjs. Perhaps not the best idea to change the value of the formcontrol inside subscribing to it. Luckily formcontrol has the option `emitEvent: false`, which doesn't trigger the `valueChanges`, otherwise you would end up with an infinite loop. So I don't see it as an issue here. Maybe someone has a better idea though :)

Buuut, so, add a form control to your input: (also import `ReactiveFormsModule`)

```
<input type="range" [formControl]="term">
```

and the TS:

```ts
alive = true; // can be used to unsubscribe to valueChanges
term = new FormControl();

constructor() {
  this.term.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive), 
      // add any wanted time to delay until next lines are executed while value changes
      debounceTime(700), 
      switchMap(val => { // switchmap cancels any previous inputs
        // do calculations and return observable of the value
        // here actually set your value, I have just made dummy for sample
        this.term.setValue(val + 5, { emitEvent: false })
        return of(val)
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.alive = false;
}
```

A **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmpnpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using `(change)` instead of `(input)`.

Comment: I did this initially - but I also need the value to calculate before the mouse button is lifted

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the change event and have a reference to the input, rather than use `this`

```
<input type="range" min="6" #ref max="60" step="6" [(ngModel)]="term" (change)="calculateTerm(ref.term)" class="slider" id="term">
```

---

Material Slider has this listener built in...

```
<mat-slider min="6" #ref max="60" step="6" [(ngModel)]="term" class="slider" (input)="calculateTerm($event)"></mat-slider>
onInputChange(event: MatSliderChange) {
  console.log("This is emitted as the thumb slides");
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

Comment: I did this initially - but I also need the value to calculate before the mouse button is lifted

Comment: Well, it's not quite the answer to your question, but Mat Slider has that built in, I revised my response